# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name=ctl00$MainContent$mainProgress]

Tags: jquery

I am using jquery 1.3.2 but I have updated to the latest version:

The following does not work with the latest version of jquery - what is going wrong here??

```
var input = $(this);

            // get the associated label using the input's id
            var label = $('label[for=' + input.attr('id') + ']');

            //get type, for classname suffix 
            var inputType = (input.is('[type=checkbox]')) ? 'checkbox' : 'radio';

            // wrap the input + label in a div 
            $('<div class="custom-' + inputType + '"></div>').insertBefore(input).append(input, label);

            // find all inputs in this set using the shared name attribute
            var allInputs = $('input[name=' + input.attr('name') + ']');
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try changing the last line to this:

```
var allInputs = $('input[name="' + input.attr('name') + '"]');
```

Comment: Thanx! You saved me some time. From the version 1.8.0 double quotes became required...